# How override void method

Tags: c#

I have abstract class with virtual method:

```
public virtual async Task Response(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    some logic here..
}
```

In child class I don't need this logic is there more elegant way to do this:

```
public override async Task Response(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```cs
public override Task Response(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

note no `async` modifier here. This avoids all allocations and state machinery, by simply reusing a single shared `Task` instance that is marked as pre-completed.

Answer (score 0):

`public override async Task Response(CancellationToken cancellationToken) { base.Response(cancellationToken); }`

if you use virtual word you have to override the parent method. otherwise you have to use the abstract method.